# Wordpress wp_query() multiple post-types with specific taxonomy terms

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a Wordpress query that includes all the standard blog posts and also the custom-post-type 'podcast' which have the taxonomy of 'series' and term 'video-blogs'. So far I've got:

```
$custom_query_args = array(
'post_type' => array('post', 'podcast'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'series',
            'term' => 'video-blogs'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
        ),
    ),
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

But it keeps triggering an error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object".

If I pull the 'tax_query' out it works as expected, pulling in all posts from both post and podcast post-types but I can't find a way to make the selection I'm after.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `'term' => 'video-blogs'` - the correct key is `terms` (plural) not `term` (singular)